# How to use a launch storyboard or XIB?

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript, nativescript-vue

### iOS App Store did not reject but downloaded app can not complete app launch

*Published version in App Store stays on startup then closes.*

My [NativeScript-Vue](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/introduction/) app was updated from NS v6

1. I have re-generated splash images
2. runs **fine** through `ns run ios --device` or `ns run ios --emulator`
3. I can run app on iphone 6S using Xcode too
4. I can even publish to Apple Store and **it's excepted.**

**But released app can not start and stays in the launch screen for a while then closes.**

It looks like It's the same error I was getting in my previous attempt to build.

My app runs only if **Main Interface** area is empty

[image: must be empty]

If I select *LaunchScreen* or *LaunchScreen.storyboard* app stays on launchScreen for ever.

---

#### Details:

I am getting errors after build analysis such as;

```
/Users/user/Documents/myapp-mobil/platforms/ios/Pods/MaterialComponents/components/Tabs/src

/MDCTabBarViewController.m:213:5: nil passed to a callee that requires a non-null 1st parameter
```

and

```
/Users/cemkaan/Documents/myapp-mobil/platforms/ios/sebappmobil/Resources/Assets.xcassets:1:1: Launch images are deprecated in iOS 13.0. Use a launch storyboard or XIB instead.
```

**iOS Development Target:** 12.4

It was **rejected** from the app store with a Binary Rejected notice

[iOS crash log which I have shared as a gist.](https://gist.github.com/kaanguru/db058fd5a1d88c6f2aad50f917f552c3) says:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
UNUSED SPACE AT START

      __TEXT                   1003e8000-1003ec000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...p/myappmobil
```

**Am I doing something wrong in **Main Interface** area?**

*Is there any way to determine; why the published version can not complete the app launch?*

[image: main interface]

Comment: Have you tried renaming your storyboard to something else than "LaunchScreen" ?

Comment: Do I need Main Interface to be filled? Where can I learn about Xcode Deployment Info settings more in detail?

Comment: See il your last screen: you set "Main interface" as LaunchScreen which is an image used as... a LaunchScreen in the section below. Since the Main Interface field will remove the file extension, it tries to use the Launchscreen image, although it expects a storyboard.

Comment: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev91fe7130a